# No operator== match for std::string?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I got a strange problem with my program. So in the header I got something like this:

```
#ifndef SET1_INCLUDED
#define SET1_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef std::string ItemType;
class Set1{
  public:
  ------some public constructor and method in here-------
  private:
  ItemType setMember[100];
}
```

in 1 part of my function in the Set1.cpp file I got something like this :

```
if (setMember[i] == "foo") {exist = true;}
```

In this case, I got an error message that says "no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'ItemType' ". However, if I change the std::string in the typedef into int or unsigned long, and change "foo" to some random number, the code works perfectly. Any suggestion? thx

Comment: did you `#include <string>` ?

Comment: I don't like the combination `using namespace std` and `std::string` (you should be using one or the other). But then, that could be just me and others may disagree.

Answer (score 8):

You are missing the header file `<string>`, which means that you don't have all of the global `operator ==` definitions visible in your program.  This is likely the case of your problem.

To fix this, try adding in this line:

```
#include <string>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include string header file to bring relative types and operator to scope.

```
#include <string>
```

Note:
    It's bad coding practice to pull in everything from std namespace in header file.

```
//using namespace std;
```